# how can i add an radio image control in Elementor Page Builder

Tags: wordpress, elementor

i want to create a radio image control in Elementor that when i set in as new control like this codes it show me an radio image ->"RADIO_IMAGE" in setting.

```
$this->add_control(
  'radio_image_control',
        [
            'label' => esc_html__('Select one layout',TEXTDOMAIN),
            'type' => Controls_Manager::RADIO_IMAGE,
            'options' => [
               '1' => esc_html__('Layout 1', TEXTDOMAIN),
               '2' => esc_html__('Layout 2', TEXTDOMAIN),
            ],
            'default' => '1',
        ]
    );
```

if someone have experience about this or now something please help thanks a lot.

i have tried with Elementor site emoj example as emoj.php file but it didn't work because i didn't know after add sample code where finaly i should include emoj.php file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no control as you used the **radio_image_control** in Elementor.